# Background/Hero video not resizing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page that has a video as the background. I have tried multiple attempts at making this happen but no matter what I do the video always looks like pictured. It will not resize at all.

[image in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH2hf.png)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .hero-section {
    position: relative;
    height: 85vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
  }

video{
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .hero-section {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class='hero section'>
        <video autoplay muted loop playinline src='images/uhoh.mp4'></video>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an image as your video src?

Comment: You have typo in hero section. It’s one class with hyphen between the words.

Answer (score 0):

If you set height to auto it scales with the width.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.hero-section {
  position: relative;
  height: 85vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;

}

video {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  
 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .hero-section {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='hero section'>
    <video controls autoplay muted loop playinline src='https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4'></video>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```